# how to create a new application in stage wepay after having an account already

Tags: wepay

i have a seemingly simple question but it seems impossible?

i have a stage wepay account.

I already have an application account there.

I want to add a new application account.

how do i do it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have registered in the test environment, but it says that I have no applications authorized..

Answer (score 1):

I guess one account can run only single application. You won't be able to have multiple application account from single user account.

You better create a new account and make application. Delete the old application and change the primary email in the second account.